# How I can get correct splash image programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible get correct splash image (for example landscape for iPad with iOS 6) programmatically? To don't perform all check for iPad, screen size and iOS version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom splash image by using `LaunchImage.storyboard`. But keep in mind, that you can't use custom fonts in splash view controller or perform any code

Answer (score 0):

Just have the splash screen in the following names and dimensions:

1. iPhone Portrait/Landscape (*iPhone doesn't support Landscape splash screen*)

   - "**Default.png**" <sup>320 x 480</sup>
   - "**Default@2x.png**" <sup>640 x 960</sup>
   - "**Default-568h@2x.png**" <sup>640 x 1136</sup>
2. iPad Portrait

   - "**Default-Portrait.png**" <sup>*768 x 1024*</sup>
   - "**Default-Portrait@2x.png**" <sup>*1536 x 2048*</sup>
3. iPad Landscape

   - "**Default-Landscape.png**" <sup>*1024 x 748*</sup>
   - "**Default-Landscape@2x.png**" <sup>*2048 x 1536*</sup>

---

FYI: Images having `@2x` in them are automatically picked up for Retina display devices.

To quote ref: [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html):

> ### Updating Your Image Resource Files
>
> Apps running in iOS 4 should now include two separate files for each image resource. One file provides a standard-resolution version of a given image, and the second provides a high-resolution version of the same image.
>   The naming conventions for each pair of image files is as follows:
>
> - Standard: *[ImageName][device_modifier].[filename_extension]*
> - High resolution: *[ImageName]@2x[device_modifier].[filename_extension]*
>
> The [ImageName] and [filename_extension] portions of each name specify
>   the usual name and extension for the file.
>   The [device_modifier] portion is optional and contains either the string **~ipad** or **~iphone**.
>   You include one of these modifiers when you want to specify different versions of an image for iPad and iPhone.
>   The inclusion of the **@2x** modifier for the high-resolution image is new and lets the system know that the image is the high-resolution variant of the standard image.

---

So, when it comes to proper dimension for images you need not do much programmatically

---

Other references:
 - [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I asked - Is there way to do it automatically. I know how resources named in device bundle and how load image from bundle, but the main idea - don't perform all if-else checks for the ipad/iphone; ios version (6/7); landscape/portrait orientation).  (and you wrong about images name - for example in my project they have names: "LaunchImage.png" and etc (@2x, ~ipad, etc...)

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko : ok... but I still don't follow what you mean by `don't perform all if-else checks for ipad/iphone`. **How about you add one your if/else conditions to your question in order to clear a few things up?** Also, the naming can be anything you want as long as you hook them up properly. So you can name it `Default.png` or `LaunchImage.png` or `[YourAppName].png`